# Error connecting to Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I tried to connect to Active Directory to get current user's name, but I get an error instead:

> The server could not be contacted.

Code:

```
var identityName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "\\MyDomain.local", null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer))
    using (userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, identityName))
    {
        lblUserName.Text = userPrincipal.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should have backslashes in your domain name - try this: `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain.local", null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer))`

Comment: I tried it before it doesn't work. Thank you i found solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
            System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        string[] a = Context.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');


        System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ADEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + a[0] + "/" + a[1]);
        lblUserName.Text = ADEntry.Properties["FullName"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: But the `WinNT://` provider is using **machine-local** accounts - ***NOT*** Active Directory accounts ....

Comment: Yes as you said when I publish the web app into iis it's show me error " ndex was outside the bounds of the array." but locally it's work :(